# Copying int to different memory location, receiving extra bytes than expected

Tags: c, pointers

Trying to pre-pend a 2 byte message length, after getting the length in a 4 byte int. I use memcpy to copy 2 bytes of the int. When I look at the second byte I copied, it is as expected, but accessing the first byte actually prints 4 bytes.

I would expect that dest[0] and dest[1] both contain 1 byte of the int. whether or not it's a significant byte, or the order is switched... I can throw in an offset on the memcpy or reversing 0 and 1. It does not have to be portable, I would just like it to work.

The same error is happening in Windows with LoadRunner and Ubuntu with GCC - so I have at least tried to rule out portability as a cause.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I am suspecting it's related to my lack of using pointers recently? Is there a better approach to cast an int to a short and then put it in the first 2 bytes of a buffer?

```
char* src;
char* dest;
int len = 2753; // Hex - AC1
src=(char*)malloc(len);
dest=(char*)malloc(len+2);

memcpy(dest, &len, 2);
memcpy(dest+2, src, len);

printf("dest[0]: %02x", dest[0]); 
// expected result: c1
// actual result: ffffffc1

printf("dest[1]: %02x", dest[1]); 
// expected result: 0a
// actual result: 0a
```

Comment: Use `unsigned char* dest;` or `printf("dest[0]: %02hhx", (unsigned) dest[0]);` or `printf("dest[0]: %02x", (unsigned char) dest[0]);` etc.  All you are seeing is the sign extension of a negative value in `dest[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just take a random two bytes out of a four byte object and call it a cast to short.

You will need to copy your int into a two byte int before doing your memcpy.

But actually, that isn't the best way to do it either, because you have no control over the byte order of an integer.

Your code should look like this:

```
dest[0] = ((unsigned)len >> 8) & 0xFF;
dest[1] = ((unsigned)len) & 0xFF;
```

That should write it out in network byte order aka big endian. All of the standard network protocols use this byte order.

And I'd add something like:

```
assert( ((unsigned)len & 0xFFFF0000) == 0 ); // should be nothing in the high bytes
```

Comment: I had a feeling this is the direction I needed to go. However, with the sample you gave, now dest[1] has the output as ffffffc1, and dest[0] is 0a.

Comment: @Stephen: Looks right. 0xAC1 right? The F's in 0xFFFFFFC1 come from sign extension. The C has the high bit set and since it is a signed value, it is extending that sign bit all the way across the larger integer.

Comment: Alright, so disregarding the printed value, the memory value in dest[0] and dest[1] is correct? And I get extended to 4 bytes when printing. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are using `printf` incorrectly. This

```
printf("dest[0]: %02x", dest[0]);
```

uses `x` format specifier in `printf`. `x` format specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. Not `char`, but `unsigned int` and only `unsigned int` (or alternatively an `int` with non-negative value).

The immediate argument you supplied has type `char`, which is probably signed on your platform. This means that your `dest[0]` contains `-63`. A variadic argument of type `char` is automatically promoted to type `int`, which turns `0xc1` into `0xffffffc1` (as a signed representation of `-63` in type `int`). Since `printf` expects an `unsigned int` value and you are passing a negative `int` value instead, the behavior is undefined. The printout that you see is nothing more than a manifestation of that undefined behavior. It is meaningless.

One proper way to print `dest[0]` in this case would be

```
printf("dest[0]: %02x", (unsigned) dest[0]);
```

I'm pretty sure the output will still be `ffffffc1`, but in this case `0xffffffc1` is the prefectly expected result of integer conversion from negative `-63` value to `unsigned int` type. Nothing unusual here.

Alternatively you can do

```
printf("dest[0]: %02x", (unsigned char) dest[0]);
```

which should give you your desired `c1` output. Note that the conversion to `int` takes place in this case as well, but since the original value is positive (`193`), the result of the conversion to `int` is positive too and `printf` works properly.

Finally, if you want to work with raw memory directly, the proper type to use would be `unsigned char` from the very beginning. Not `char`, but `unsigned char`.

Secondly, an object of type `int` may easily occupy more than two 8-bit bytes. Depending on the platform, the `0xA` and `0xC1` values might end up in completely different portions of the memory region occupied by that `int` object. You should not expect that copying the first two bytes of an `int` object will copy the `0xAC1` portion specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the printf problem. I can basically replicate for both by changing len to be 50128 or something where the high bit is set in both bytes. Makes sense. I think for the second issue, I'm pretty bound to using the LoadRunner C environment for this, and don't really need to worry about that, but point taken.

Comment: Yea, actually I didn't know that thing about unsigned char. I think that may have contributed here. If I initialize the 2 pointers as unsigned char instead of char, I don't need the typecast when printing.

Comment: 1) "Moreover, in modern C it is guaranteed to occupy at least four 8-but bytes" is not true.  An `int` in 2014 still only must meet the minimum range of -32767 to 32767 per the C11 spec.  Hundreds of millions of embedded processors per year use 16-bit `int`. 2) Could use `printf("dest[0]: %02hhx", (unsigned) dest[0]);` But other than those, nice answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

You make the assumption that an "int" is two bytes. What justification do you have for that? Your code is highly unportable.

You make another assumption that "char" is unsigned. What justification do you have for that? Again, your code is highly unportable.

You make another assumption about the ordering of bytes in an int. What justification do you have for that? Again, your code is highly unportable.

Comment: You're not wrong, but I'm not exactly sure if those points are the issue I'm facing. I am assuming int is 4 bytes and I only care about 2 bytes. I have tried a cast to short, and the same thing happens (filling 4 bytes at the dest[0]).

Answer (score 0):

instead of the literal 2, use sizeof(int). Never hard code the size of a type.

If this code should be portable, you should not use int, but a fixed size datatype. 
If you need 16 bit, you could use `int16_t`.

Also, the printing of the chars would need a cast to unsigned. Now, the char is upcasted to an int, and the sign is extended. This gives the initial FFFF's

Comment: I only need to allocate enough space to hold an additional 2 bytes, not 2 ints. Basically, casting the int to short.

Comment: yea, you're right about needing a cast to unsigned char to print. that gets rid of the FFFFFF. But, I don't really care how it prints out... does the internal representation in dest[0] contain that or not?